# You need to choose options for your item in Magento2 after running command indexer:reindex

Tags: reindex, magento2.3

I Moved database and webserver files from one server to another. After moving everything works fine. But when i run php bin/magento indexer:reindex on new server then while adding products programmatically it shows me this error on new server.
You need to choose options for your item
[image]

Actually after debugging i found that collection is not returning me data with attributes however i added $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*') in my code. But before running indexer:reindex command it returns me all data with all attributes. After running command it will not return collection with attributes. I am using magento 2.3 ce.

After further dubug i found that in my configurations flat table was on
[image]

After turning selecting No the issue disappear. 
But the problem is why i cant load my collection with attributes when use flat catalog product is enables. 
Ofcourse after enabling flat catalog we will get more better performance.But how we fix this issue with flat catalog enables.